# transform:rotate not working - but works on original mockup

Tags: css, animation, transform, css-animations

I made a fidget spinner animation which we are using for a Sale.

You can see it working perfectly here: https://jsfiddle.net/e2tt2mao/448/

However when I apply the same/similar code to the "scene" i am currently making I cant get it to spin at all...

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/uzfpqysc/8/

I have tried everything.. I'm not sure why it wont spin in my "second js fiddle link"

Any help is much appreciated!

```
    @-webkit-keyframes rotating /* Safari and Chrome */ {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.rotating {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the `.rotating` span had not width and height because the images inside were absolute positioned. I have defined a width and height for the span and have it a transform origin of `transform-origin: 50% 50%;`. I have also attempted to centrally position the `.rotating` span, but you may want to adjust it.

https://jsfiddle.net/WizardCoder/uzfpqysc/11/

EDIT: Here is the responsive version. I had to adjust the styles for `.animateVSS` very slightly to allow me to properly center the spinner. It will do the same as what your styling was doing just a slightly different approach.

https://jsfiddle.net/WizardCoder/uzfpqysc/12/

Comment: Thanks! However this is a responsive project. It was fully responsive before. Now its not with your changes and im not sure how to fix that. As now scaling on the image is broken.

Comment: I didn't notice it was responsive. I have added an update fiddle.

Comment: Nice! That is exactly right! Thanks so much for the help Wizard!